# How to make reactjs and flaskapi running on same port number

Tags: reactjs, python-3.x

I have my flask app running in backend on port number 5000 and reactjs front end running on port number 3000, How can I make both running on same port number?
Can anyone help on this.
It would be great help.

Comment: You can't have 2 programs listening on the same tcp port at the same time.

Comment: Not possible, and I don't see why you would want to do that given that you can set flask to run on any port you want with a simple command: app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)

Answer (score 0):

You can't. It is not about React. It is how networking works. Each port can only bind to one and only one process.

However, I kind of get what you are trying to achieve, you may use proxy to achieve a similar effect.
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development